# --url_prefix not supported anymore, so Flower can only run on root now?

Tags: celery, django-celery, djcelery, flower

Although using --url_prefix parameter does not give error when running Flower, but it doesn't work anymore. Also deprecated is written on this parameter in the comments in latest source code. So does there exist an alternative to this parameter or from now on [Flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) can only be run on root?

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/414